# How to perform incremental retrieval on NetSuite API?

Tags: netsuite

Using the WebService API of NetSuite (using C#/.NET), I would like to retrieve all `SalesOrder`(s) and all `PurchaseOrder`(s) using some incremental data retrieval pattern where not all data get redownloaded each time; only the data that have actually changed. It's unclear to me how to achieve this with the NetSuite search feature.

Any hint?

Comment: Did you try using a SavedSearch?

Comment: I am not too sure how `SavedSearch` could possibly address the problem at hand.

Comment: what exactly you want to do with the SO and PO, you want to store them into a CSV? or what is that you want to do. I could help you in a much better way then

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no records are created during the search duration,

Use Transaction Searches to fetch data and keep the result sorted on internalId.

Next time you fetch the data add a filter internalid greater than, this way you can incrementally fetch the data.

Comment: Thanks! Does this approach guarantees that a modified record is going to appear with an incremented 'internalid'? Otherwise, this approach would be missing all the changes brought to modified to "old" records.

Comment: Do you want to fetch all the records in consecutive searches at given point of time or the time difference between two searches would be high?

Comment: Well in that case you should prefer to sort and filter by created date or last modified date